# Angular 2 interceptor is not working properly

Tags: angular, http, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to create a custom http class that extends Http to work like AngularJS interceptors on Angular 2. I followed other Stackoverflow questions and some several tutorials but I always get the same error and I can't find the solution.

I have the following Http interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers, Request } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        options = new RequestOptions();
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('X-Auth-Token', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access-token'));
        options.headers = headers;
        return super.request(url, options);
    }
}
```

And I've add it to the app.module like this:

```
  providers: [{
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: loadCustomHttp,
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  }],

  export function loadCustomHttp(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
  return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions);
}
```

I don't get any error with this configuration but when I do any request, I get a 401 because the authentication header wasn't added. A sample request could be:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

  getExample() {
    let url = this.urlBase + '/test';

    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url could be one of two different types, string or Request, so

```
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
let token = localStorage.getItem('access-token');

if (token) {
  if (typeof url === 'string') {
    if (!options) {
      options = { headers: new Headers() };
    }
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    console.log('Url is string', options.headers.get('Authorization'));
  } else {
    url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    console.log('Url is Request', url.headers.get('Authorization'));
  }
}

return super.request(url, options);
}
```